# Can I use a wireless router as a repeater?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, repeater

I have a wireless TP-Link TL-WR941ND router connected to the internet, but I can't get a good signal in the other end of my house. I have a spare Edimax BR-6226n wireless router.

Is it possible to use it to somehow increase the signal of my wifi network?  If not, is it possible to do it with a computer attached (I got lots of old ones around)?

Comment: Which exact models do you have?

Comment: TP-Link: TL-WR941ND

Comment: Edimax: BR-6226n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On some models this is not possible because they don't have that feature. But luckily, your Edimax supports wireless bridging:

> Supports AP, AP Client, Bridge, Bridge+ WDS and Universal Repeater mode

1. Go into your settings by typing the Router's IP address
2. In "Basic Settings", under "Mode", select "Universal Repeater" mode
3. Under ESSID, enter an arbitrary name for your repeating router
4. Under Root SSID, enter the SSID of your original router's network

See [the manual](http://www.edimax.com/images/Image/manual/Wireless/BR-6225n/BR-6225N_Manual.zip) for more details.

Comment: Ended up using its WISP function, but I guess this would work too. Thanks!

Comment: Almost every (if not definitely every) router has the ability to not assign DHCP on it's own and instead act as a repeater/hub by connecting it with a LAN input (not WAN) and getting it's own IP. The router that it connects to then issues the DHCP addresses and the network if unified. In terms of wireless synchronization, they do need to provide the same specs and not all routers are as capable.

Answer (score 0):

If it supports wireless bridging, then yes.

Answer (score -1):

Go to DD-WRT.com and find a router that is supported. The DD-WRT firmware has support for Bridging. I like the Linksys WRT56GL router. It came with Linux firmware and is easy to flash with DD-WRT

Comment: Why would the OP need a new router if the one he has already supports bridging?